# How do I write a regex that matches a word and then displays a image?

Tags: jquery, regex

I am working on a widget & here is the code I have so far:

```
$(".number-plate").html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/([a-z0-9])/ig, '<img src="plate-widget/$1.gif" alt="$1" />');
});
```

What I would like to happen is if the individual characters make up the work 'ANY', then I want to display a single image of the word, instead of 3 different images?

Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to match the word `"ANY"` or a single characters, if this is so you could use the following:

```
/(ANY|[A-Za-z0-9])/g
```

Comment: Ghost - That's worked in that it excludes the word 'ANY'...How do I write a regex that matches/replaces the word 'ANY'?